# Re-enable Full Menu, Ribbon in ms access 2010

Tags: vba, ribbon, ms-access-2010

I wanted my Access program to look like standalone and I got rid of all menus from customize. I was still seeing ribbon and office icon, where I would revert that back. Then I found this awesome answer to hide ribbon (including all menu) [Disabling the Ribbon Bar Except for Reports (Print Preview) In MS-Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442894/disabling-the-ribbon-bar-except-for-reports-print-preview-in-ms-access)
So, I used

```
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
```

Then comes new problem 
Now I cannot modify anything, design and more codes. How do I revert back?

Thanks

Edit: I know,

```
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarYes
```

may be way to go, but I cannot access VBA too.

Ananta

Comment: I don't have a machine available at the moment, but maybe you can access Access from the PowerShell and fire the command from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold the shift key while you open the database, then press `alt+F11` and see if that gets the code window.

Comment: Great, So holding the shift key did the magic, I could see everything back...Thank you very much